# Unwanted spacing between inline-table elements

Tags: css, inline, margin

I want to make dynamic width columns inside of dynamic width div. Everything seems to be working just fine, but if I want to make the sum of column widths 100%, the third column jumps down even though there is still space. And I can't get rid of the spacing after each column. 
Maybe some of you might know why?
Here is my fiddle!
http://jsfiddle.net/vMe5L/
My code:

```
<style>
.content { width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: gray; }
.left { width: 20%; display: inline-table; height: 100%; background-color: red; }
.middle { width: 30%; display: inline-table; height: 100%; background-color: blue; } 
.right { width: 47%; display: inline-table; height: 100%; background-color: yellow; }
</style>

<div class="content">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance, you guys are amazing.

Comment: As about "why", text outside tags counts as well.

Comment: Float:right made it stay in container

Comment: Any specific reason for using `inline-table` over `table-cell`?

Comment: Just connect the dots:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZagHq/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Floating is not an option here. But thank you anyway!

Comment: I discovered, that inline-table with % width works perfectly for responsive design. I detect viewport height and width with javascript and then set columns with % width. Put images as a background and can make mosaic which always looks good and does not change proportions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either float the elements, or remove the whitespace in between. On inline elements (which includes styling them to `display: inline-table` or `inline-block`), whitespace is shown too, even if it is collapsed to a single space. So:

```
<div class="content"><div class="left"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="right"></div></div>
```

works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `table` and `table-cell` display.

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/vMe5L/5/

*CSS*:

```
div { box-sizing: border-box; }
.content { display: table; width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: gray; }
.left { width: 20%; display: table-cell; height: 100%; background-color: red; }
.middle { width: 30%; display: table-cell; height: 100%; background-color: blue; } 
.right { width: 50%; display: table-cell; height: 100%; background-color: yellow; }
```

*Update*:

If you want to stick to `inline-table`, then get rid of the white spaces. The best way would to introduce comments:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="left"></div><!--
    --><div class="middle"></div><!--
    --><div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMe5L/8/)

Changes made,
added css `display:table` to outer class content, and inner classes changed to `display:table-cell;`